# Nested JOIN IN Hibernate Criteria Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a SQL QUERY Like this.

```
    SELECT a.id,a.name,b.id,b.name,c.id,c.name from TableA a
    LEFT JOIN (TableB b INNER JOIN TableC c on c.bid=b.id and c.name in('err','fgh')) 
    on b.aid=a.id
```

I want to convert it into Hibernate Criteria query.Is there any solution for that?

Here is the structure of table. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1b43/1

The expected output is:

```
Aid Aname   Bid    Bname       Cid   Cname
1   abc     3      qwe         7     err
1   abc     3      qwe         8     err
1   abc     5      der         12    fgh
2   xyz     NULL   NULL        NULL  NULL
```

Comment: Are you want data in 3 pairs ? means `id-name` like so..

Comment: It is just an example of my requirement. But I want this type of nested join.

Comment: How do you know which column is a and which is b, etc? And I don't understand why b.id is NULL in the last row. I mean, I understand why it is - i just don't get why you'd want it to be!

Comment: I want All records of TableA and and records of TableB and TableC which has met condition.It is a requirement of my project.